# Should we occasionally "upgrade" our Mercurial repositories as new versions of Mercurial come out?

Tags: mercurial, repository

Are there some reasons to occasionally upgrade mercurial repositories using the instructions in [Upgrading Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/UpgradingMercurial) (`hg clone --pull`)

Does advice about that differ for the repositories I keep on my laptop, versus the central shared repository for a project/continuous integration/etc.  (For instance, could we run into problems if one developer has an old version of the client?)

And how do you tell what version's format a repository was built with, and whether there's something to be gained?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using an extremely large repository (something on the scale of the mozilla-central repository) it shouldn't matter what repository format you are using on the client or server. Future versions of mercurial will always be able to talk to repositories created by old versions and old versions will be able to pull from repositories created by new versions of mercurial.